# Convergence of random variable to a negative constant

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $X_n$ be the sequence of R.Vs and $X_n\overset{P}{\rightarrow}A$ (or $X_n\rightarrow A$ almost surely) where $A<0$

I want to prove that $Pr[X_n < 0] \rightarrow 1$ (or $X_n < A$ almost surely).

The almost surely case is obvious from the definition of the convergence, but in the case in with the convergence in probability how do I see it holds from the following? (used the definition)
$$  \left(\forall \varepsilon > 0\right) \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Pr\left[ |X_n - A| \leq \varepsilon \right] = 1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your definition of convergence in probability, we must have

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Pr[|X_n - A| \le \frac{|A|}{3}] = 1$

But since $A < 0$, we know that $|X_n - A| \le \frac{|A|}{3}$ implies that $X_n < 0$. So, we have:

$\{|X_n-A| \le \frac{|A|}{3}\} \subset \{ X_n < 0 \}$.

Thus, $\Pr[ X_n < 0] \ge \Pr[|X_n-A| \le \frac{|A|}{3}]$ for all $n$. Since the latter probability converges to $1$, we must have:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Pr[X_n < 0] = 1$.